# Yii Undefined index

Tags: php, yii

Hi I'm using Yii framework and trying to submit my data from view but It got error, says Undefined index, here's the printscreen:
[image: undefined index: nomorPemesanan]

And the codes are:

Here's my model:

```
<?php
class ConfirmPayment extends CActiveRecord{

public $nomorPemesanan; //nomorpemesanan
public $bankAsal; // nama bank asal
public $pemilikRekAsal; // nama pemilik rek asal
public $bankTujuan; //nama bank tujuan transfer
public $nominalTransfer; // nominal transfer / jumlah uang yang di transfer

public $dataPaymentText;

public static function model($className = __CLASS__){
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function tableName(){
    return 'tbl_confirm_payment';
}

public function afterFind(){
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->dataPaymentText = explode('#',$this->text_detail); 
}

public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('order_code,text_detail','required'),
        array('nomorPemesanan,bankAsal,pemilikRekAsal,bankTujuan,nominalTransfer','required'),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels(){
    return array(
        'id'=>'ID Konfirmasi',
        'nomorPemesanan'=>'Nomor Pemesanan',
        'pemilikRekAsal'=>'Nama Pemilik Rekening Asal',
        'bankAsal'=>'Nama Bank Asal',
        'bankTujuan'=>'Bank Tujuan Transfer',
        'nominalTransfer'=>'Jumlah yang ditransfer',
    );
}

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function actionOrders($id = '')
    {
        // component IsAuth
        IsAuth::Customer();
        // konfirmasi pembayaran
        if (isset($_GET['confirm']))
        {
            // panggil model Confirmpayment
            $model = new ConfirmPayment;
            // jika data ConfirmPayment dikirim dengan method $_POST
            if (isset($_POST['ConfirmPayment']))
            {
                // set value field
                $order_code = $_POST['ConfirmPayment']['nomorPemesanan'];
                $model->attributes = $_POST['ConfirmPayment'];
                $model->order_code = $_POST['ConfirmPayment']['nomorPemesanan'];
                $model->text_detail .= $_POST['ConfirmPayment']['bankAsal'] . '#';
                $model->text_detail .= $_POST['ConfirmPayment']['pemilikRekAsal'] . '#';
                $model->text_detail .= $_POST['ConfirmPayment']['bankTujuan'] . '#';
                $model->text_detail .= $_POST['ConfirmPayment']['nominalTransfer'] . '#';
                // jika data confirmPayment disimpan maka
                if ($model->save())
                {
                    // find data order by attributes berdasarkan order_code
                    $modelOrder = Order::model()->findByAttributes(array('order_code' => $order_code));
                    // set field payment_status dari 0 menjadi 1, artinya pembayaran sudah dikonfirmasi
                    $modelOrder->payment_status =1;
                    exit(CActiveForm::validate($modelOrder));
                    // simpan
                    $modelOrder->save();
                    // setFlash konfirmasi pembayaran sukses
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Belanjaan dengan nomor pesanan #'.$order_code.' berhasil dikonfirmasi!');
                    // redirect
                    $this->redirect(array('orders'));
                    return;
                }
            }
            // render ke file customer/confirm_payment
            $this->render('confirm_payment', array('model' => $model));
            return;
        }
        // untuk view list_orders
        if (empty($id))
        {
            // panggil model Order dan function search
            $model = new Order('search');
            // hapus default values pada attributes
            $model->unsetAttributes();
            // untuk filter data Order berdasarkan id customer
            $model->customer_id = Yii::app()->user->customerId;
            // jika data order dikirim view get
            if (isset($_GET['Order']))
            {
                // set attributes untuk pencarian
                $model->attributes = $_GET['Order'];
            }
            // render ke file customer/list_orders
            $this->render('list_orders', array('model' => $model));
            return;
        }
        // untuk view detail_order
        if (!empty($id))
        {
            // join query untuk mendapatkan detail_order
            $dataOrderDetail = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('tbl_orders.*,tbl_orderdetail.*,tbl_products.*')
                    ->from('tbl_orders')
                    ->join('tbl_orderdetail', 'tbl_orderdetail.order_id = tbl_orders.id')
                    ->join('tbl_products', 'tbl_products.id = tbl_orderdetail.product_id')
                    ->where('tbl_orders.id=:id_order', array(':id_order' => $id))
                    ->queryAll();
            // join query untuk mendapatkan data order dan customer
            $dataOrder = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('tbl_orders.*, tbl_customer.customer_name')
                    ->from('tbl_orders')->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_orders.customer_id = tbl_customer.id')
                    ->where('tbl_orders.id=:id', array(':id' => $id))
                    ->queryRow();
            // render ke view customer/detail_order
            $this->render('detail_order', array(
                'dataOrder' => $dataOrder,
                'orderDetail' => $dataOrderDetail,
                'subtotal' => '',
                'grandtotal' => '',
            ));
            return;
        }
```

and my view:

```
<div style="padding:5px 10px 0 0;margin:5px 5px 15px 5px; border:1px solid #CCC;text-align: justify;">
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'nomorPemesanan'); ?></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><b><?php echo $_GET['confirm']; ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'bankAsal'); ?></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><b><?php echo CHtml::activeTelField($model, 'bankAsal'); ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'pemilikRekAsal'); ?></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><b><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'pemilikRekAsal'); ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'bankTujuan'); ?></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="Confirmpayment[bankTujuan]">
                <option value="BCA 1700-******* a.n. L******">BCA 1700-******* a.n. L******</option>
                <option value="Mandiri 150-00-********* L****** Jr">Mandiri 150-00-********* a.n. L******</option>
                <option value="BNI 1580****** a.n. L******">BNI 1580****** a.n. L******</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'nominalTransfer'); ?></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><b><?php echo CHtml::activeTelField($model, 'nominalTransfer'); ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Konfirmasi'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Hope anybody can solve this.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the nomorPemesanan active text field in your form.

You could try updating the form this way:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'nomorPemesanan'); ?></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><b><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'nomorPemesanan'); ?></b></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ok so I added <?php echo CHtml::activeHiddenField($model,'nomerPemesanan',array('value'=>$_GET['confirm']));?>  because i need to get the certain value. It doesnt gives error message, though after click the screen only displays this [] symbol, literallly.